# PLSQL: insert xml values into table without specifing columns

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I generated an xml containing all the rows of my table using  dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select * from MyTable') from dual;
```

So I have an xml like this:

```
    <ROWSET>
    <ROW>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <SURNAME>Smith</SURNAME>
      <NAME>John</NAME>
      <ADDRESS>XXX</ADDRESS>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <SURNAME>Allen</SURNAME>
     <NAME>Jim</NAME>
     <ADDRESS>YYY</ADDRESS>
     </ROW>
   </ROWSET>
```

Is it possible to re-insert the values from XML above into the same table dinamically without specifing any column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbms_xmlsave can do that for you. In it's most basic form

```
declare
   myxml clob;
   rowsv number;
   ctx dbms_xmlsave.ctxType;
begin null;
   my_xml := --  XML data
   ctx := dbms_xmlsave.newcontext('myTable');
   rows := dbms_xmlsave.insertxml(ctx,myxml);
   dbms_xmlsave.closecontext(ctx);
end;
/
```

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlsav.htm#ARPLS70043)

Comment: It mainly worls but with date columns I receive this error: ORA-29532 oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException Unparseable date: "02-LUG-19"

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to re-insert the values from XML above into the same
>   table dinamically without specifing any column name?

You can do as shown in below demo:

```
--Table having xml
CREATE TABLE xml_tab (  xml_data  XMLTYPE);

--Inserting xml                       
INSERT INTO xml_tab VALUES ( '<ROWSET>
                            <ROW>
                             <ID>1</ID>
                             <SURNAME>Smith</SURNAME>
                              <NAME>John</NAME>
                              <ADDRESS>XXX</ADDRESS>
                            </ROW>
                            <ROW>
                             <ID>2</ID>
                             <SURNAME>Allen</SURNAME>
                             <NAME>Jim</NAME>
                             <ADDRESS>YYY</ADDRESS>
                             </ROW>
                           </ROWSET>'
);
--Selecting xml
SELECT * FROM xml_tab;                        

--Table to insert records
CREATE TABLE xmtab (
    id        NUMBER,
    surname   VARCHAR2(50),
    name      VARCHAR2(50),
    address   VARCHAR2(50)
);

--Inserting into XMTAB
INSERT INTO XMTAB
SELECT xt.*
FROM xml_tab x,
    XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW'
     PASSING x.xml_data
     COLUMNS
      ID          NUMBER       PATH 'ID',
      SURNAME     VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'SURNAME',
      NAME        VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'NAME',
      ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'ADDRESS'
          ) xt
;
```

Comment: it's not the scope of the Question. Insert into XMTAB must be done dinamically without specifing columns.

Comment: @Ork To extract the values from the `XML` you need to mention the column names. It's `NOT` possible to do without that. You can still do it but the data will be saved under one columns not individual columns. Means if you remove `COLUMNS
      ID          NUMBER       PATH 'ID',
      SURNAME     VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'SURNAME',
      NAME        VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'NAME',
      ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'ADDRESS'` you still get the rows of type xmltype, which you can insert into table.  Btw why you don't want to explicitly mention the columns ?

Comment: As you can see above, user @Rene suggested the solution and it is possible. The only problem with his solution is data column format. I need to do it because I've got backup procedures on multiple tables and I don't want to create a single procedure for every table I need to backup.

Comment: `I need to do it because I've got backup procedures on multiple tables ` . The worst part playing with XML is its not very handy and its really difficult to manipulate. Although Rene solution seems working for you bt i can still see some error being faced by you. If that has been resolved you can close the question by accepting Rene's answer